# Show messagebox just once when is time greater then specified time

Tags: vb.net

I made small program which detects when is user idle.
When is idle time greater then 10s program should open only a one messagebox. But in my case are run a multiple messageboxes. I know why its happen but I dont know how I can solve it. 
Thanks for every help.

```
If (inactiveTime Is Nothing) Then

ElseIf (inactiveTime.Value.TotalSeconds > 10000) Then
        'Idle          
        Textbox1.text = "User is idle"
        Msgbox("User is idle")          
Else
        'Active           
        Textbox1.text = "User is active"                   
    End if
End if
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a class scoped Boolean variable as a flag to indicate that you are in the idle mode, reset it when user goes active, also make sure you reset the inactive time when the user goes active again.

i.e.

```
Dim idle As Boolean = False
```

then

```
If (inactiveTime Is Nothing) Then

ElseIf (inactiveTime.Value.TotalSeconds > 10000) Then
    'Idle  
    If Not idle Then
        Textbox1.text = "User is idle"
        MsgBox("User is idle")
    End If
    idle = True
Else
    'Active    
    idle = False
    inactiveTime = 0
    Textbox1.text = "User is active"
End If
```